# Cygwin help: Installing autoconf, automake, and gettext

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I would like to know how to install autoconf, automake, and gettext on my cygwin installation. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried re-running the cygwin installer? Pretty sure that was how it used to be done...

Comment: How do I run the installer again?

Comment: @RenoRex See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

#### I would like to know how to install autoconf, automake, and gettext

Run the Cygwin installer and select the following packages:

- [autoconf2.5](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fautoconf2.5%2Fautoconf2.5-2.69-2&grep=autoconf): Current version of the automatic configure script builder (installed binaries and support files)
- [automake](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fautomake%2Fautomake-9-1&grep=automake): Wrapper scripts for automake and aclocal (installed binaries and support files)
- [gettext](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fgettext%2Fgettext-0.19.7-1&grep=gettext): GNU Internationalization library and core utilities (installed binaries and support files)

---

#### How do I run the installer again?

Just run the setup program you ran when you first installed Cygwin:

> Install it by running [setup-x86.exe](http://cygwin.org/setup-x86.exe) (32-bit installation) or
>   [setup-x86_64.ex](http://cygwin.org/setup-x86_64.exe)e (64-bit installation).
>
> Use the setup program to perform a [fresh install](http://cygwin.org/install.html) or to
>   [update](http://cygwin.org/install.html) an existing installation.

Source [This is the home of the Cygwin project](http://cygwin.org/)

See [Installing and Updating Cygwin Packages](http://cygwin.org/install.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I feel the need to spread the word.

I agree with David that those need to be installed but if you need to install any package in cygwin I HIGHLY recommend using a command line package manager called "apt-cyg"! It makes installing things like this SO much easier. It allows me to get *shtuff* done.

You can go to the main site but I think this [Stack Overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286337/how-to-install-apt-cyg-for-cygwin) is more enlightening.